# XML generation from data in core data iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I am going to make an application and in that I want to store user's input in XML file and then parse it to another user,So I am confuse How can I do it, and which XML method should I use? NSXML parser,libxml,touchXML or KissXML?

Comment: Try this:: https://github.com/karelia/KSHTMLWriter

Answer (score 1):

```
  I think this link will help you to choose best type of xml parser.
```

[How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

```
   Thank You
```

Comment: Actually I have visited here, but It can not help me